# Table Section Header showing when returning from detailed view after in UISearchDisplay Controller

Tags: iphone, ios5

the following set up I have:
- A TabBarControler
  - Inside a Tab a UINavigationController
    - Inside Here a UITableViewController
      - Inside here the possibility to search entries with a UISearchDisplayController

I may not post pictures which would explain everything better but SO won't allow it.

- So I have aTable with sections and entries and a search bar.
- Now I do a search and select one of the search results to enter a detailed view
- After selecting one of the results and returning back to the search results

The Sections headers are there but I made sure in the appropriate section callbacks that there is returned a nil respective 0 value when the search table is active.
I am guessing that it is connected with the NavController but I have no clue how to send the section headers into the background again.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks,

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

... found it ... shame on me, it was a table reload call in the parent class in the ViewDidApear Method.